# Qt: Screen Shot

Tags: qt, screenshot, rgb, rgba, qpixmap

I have 3 QLabels of 1024x512 over one another (as QPixmaps). The bottom layer receives RGB datastream, the second layer receives RGBA datastream (so opacity can be turned down to see the bottom layer), and finally the third layer is an annotation overlay to be drawn on. I am trying to create a save out image of what the user is currently looking at in the window (not the full screen) at the time of the call. Any help or directions to look down (classes, members, examples, etc.) would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming all 3 `QLabel`s are under the same `QWidget` parent (perhaps using a `QStackedWidget` or `QStackedLayout`)?  If so it might be worth looking at [QWidget::render](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#render).

Comment: I matched the x-y positions of all 3 so that each label was right over each other on the mainwindow. The QScreen class member grabWindow(WId,x,y,w,h) worked for what I was trying to do.

Comment: The concept here was to overlay detections in the IR(top label) over the visible specturm (base label). I did away witht the top most label and used a form of polygon to select and isolate regions on the view (points were not directly mapped between labels, i was too lazy so.had just an absolute overlap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself...

```
QScreen *This_Screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
This_Pixmap = This_Screen->grabWindow(QWidget::winId(),x,y,1024,512);
```